# New identity for Euler's Totient Function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

A few weeks ago I discovered and proved a simple identity for Euler's totient function.  I figured that someone would have already discovered it, but I haven't been able to find it anywhere.

So I was hoping someone would be able to tell me whether or not they've seen this identity.

Here it is:

$$\phi(n)=\phi(\operatorname{rad}(n))\left(\frac{n}{\operatorname{rad}(n)}\right)$$

where $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ is the radical or square-free kernel of $n$, i.e. the product of the distinct prime factors of $n$.

I have omitted the proof because firstly, I'm still learning MathJax and am afraid it will take quite a long time to type out.  And secondly, I believe it is intuitive enough that most people familiar with the totient function should be able to see that it's true.

Like I said, it is a pretty simple identity, but nevertheless; it seems like it could be fairly useful.  It would be a bit easier to calculate $\phi(n)$ for large-ish $n$ with this identity, without the help of a program or totient function calculator.

Ex: $$\phi(450)=\phi(2\cdot3^2\cdot5^2)=\phi(2\cdot3\cdot5)\left(\frac{2\cdot3^2\cdot5^2}{2\cdot3\cdot5}\right)=(1\cdot2\cdot4)(3\cdot5)=120$$

Comment: Can you tell me why you wrote "Where", with a capital initial "W" in "Where $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ is the radical"?  I've seen lots of others do that --- so many that I have to suspect it's not merely a typo but rather that some people feels that's the right way to do it.  Since it's not the beginning of a new sentence, but makes sense only as a continuation of the sentence already underway, I am puzzled.

Comment: I don't know that I've ever seen this written out explicitly, but it's an immediate consequence of the multiplicativity of $\phi()$ along with the rule that $\phi(p^n)$ $= (p-1)p^{n-1}$ $= \phi(p)p^{n-1}$.

Comment: Note that on [the wikipedia totient page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) there is the formula $$\phi(mn)=\phi(m)\phi(n)\dfrac{(m,n)}{\phi((m,n))}$$ with $(m,n)$ denoting the GCD of $m$ and $n$...  With just a little transformation, I believe this expresses your identity or nearly so.

Comment: You are right it was incorrect, I didn't do it intentionally.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: That's an irritating feature of the editor that gets me all the time. It seems like a sort of autocorrect or something. When you end a displayed math section with "$$" and hit enter, the shift key is enabled so the next letter typed is capitalized. I don't know if it's the site or my iPad doing this (probably the latter). It's especially irritating to try to type "$a+bi$" to find it has bee "corrected" to "$a+bI$" for some reason.

Comment: @MPW It's not the site. It doesn't happen to me. Some sort of autocorrection on the I-pad runs amok.

Comment: @MPW : What editor is that??  I just clicked on "ASK QUESTION" and typed $$a+bi,$$ then on the next line "where $a$ and $b$ are real", and nothing like that happened to me.

Comment: (By the way, since I realized that my initial comment was a bit abrupt, I want to emphasize that I think it's awesome you're thinking about things this way and experimenting with formulae!  You may be in well-trod ground here, but don't let that discourage you at all.  There are unexplored wilds just down the road.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an interesting thing to notice, and you should be pleased.

As you guessed, and as Steven Stadnicki pointed out, this is not new; it follows quickly from two important properties of the $\phi$ function:

1. $\phi(p^n) = (p-1)p^{n-1}$ when $p$ is prime
2. $\phi(mn) = \phi(m)\phi(n)$ when $m$ and $n$ have no common factor

In particular, you suggested that your formula might be useful for calculating $\phi(n)$ for “large-ish $n$”, but observe that your formula requires knowing the radical of $n$, which is not in general any easier to find than the prime factorization of $n$.  (And when the radical of $n$ is *equal* to $n$, as it is when $n$ is squarefree, your formula is no help at all.) But given $n = p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ one has from (1) and (2) above that $$\begin{align}
\phi(n) & = \phi\bigl(p_1^{a_1}\bigr)\cdots\phi\bigl(p_k^{a_k}\bigr)  \\
& = (p_1-1)p_1^{a_1-1}\cdots (p_k-1)p_k^{a_k-1} \\
& = \frac{n}{p_1\cdots p_k}(p_1-1)\cdots(p_k-1) \\
& = n\left(\frac{p_1-1}{p_1}\right)\cdots \left(\frac{p_k-1}{p_k}\right) \tag{$\heartsuit$}\\
& = n\left(1-\frac1{p_1}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac1{p_k}\right)
\end{align}$$ which is well-known, and not significantly harder to compute (or perhaps easier) than your formula.  The next-to last line ($\heartsuit$) is very similar to your formula.

Comment: I would like to add that I hope I did not discourage you. You are doing real mathematics, and your claimed result is correct and sensible.

Comment: What MJD said, exactly - don't let the fact that these may be familiar results discourage you at all; your exploration is absolutely to be commended.

Comment: Thank you guys, that means a lot!  I will definitely keep working at it, and maybe one day I'll discover something new.

Answer (score 10):

Your identity
can be written as
$$
\frac{\phi(n)}{n}=\frac{\phi(\operatorname{rad}(n))}{\operatorname{rad}(n)}
$$
In this form, it is obvious, because
$$
\frac{\phi(m)}{m}=\prod_{p\mid m}\left(1-\frac1p\right)
$$
and $n$ and $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ have exactly the same prime factors.

Still, a nice observation, well done!

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\rad}{\operatorname{rad}}$

Yes this is a bit of transformation of the euler product formula; it's correct since
$$n=\prod_{i=1}p_i^{a_i}=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}p_3^{a_3}\cdots p_n^{a_n}\\
\rad(n)=p_1p_2p_3\cdots p_n\\\varphi(\rad(n))=(p_1-1)(p_2-1)(p_3-1)\cdots (p_n-1)\\
\frac{n}{\rad(n)}=p_1^{a_1-1}p_2^{a_2-1}p_3^{a_3-1}\cdots p_n^{a_n-1}\\
\varphi(\rad(n))\left(\frac{n}{\rad(n)}\right)=n\left(1-\frac{1}{p_1}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{p_2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{p_3}\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{1}{p_n}\right)$$
[Which is all ready known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Euler.27s_product_formula)